# Google Maps API - marker on my geo position

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating google map this way.

```
function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.684374, 37.849364),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

How i can put marker on map, on place i want?

Thanks

Comment: We don't know where is the place you want. You need to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define LatLng outside of map_options.

`var myLat = new google.maps.LatLng(55.684374, 37.849364)`

Inside map_options you can pass `myLat` to `center`

You already have a map property `var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)`. You can use that property and create new Marker

`var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLat,
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});`

For more informations please consult [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add)